How safe are NTA-877 e-bike helmets for real world use?
If a helmet designed for urban, class 3 e-bike riding passes the NTA-8776 standard, will it actually be sufficiently for urban, class 3 e-bike riding? I can imagine several scenarios where meeting the standard doesn't reflect real world safety.
For example, does the standard reflect a "bare minimum" level of safety, a "you'll be fine no matter what" level of safety, or somewhere in between? If it's in-between, where on the spectrum is it?
To take another perspective, is knowing that a helmet meets NTA-8776 enough to conclude the helmet is safe? If not, what other requirements should be met for a helmet to be sufficiently safe?
More broadly, how does one translate the NTA-8776 standard, which is based on laboratory testing, into real world effectiveness outside of a laboratory?

"you'll be fine no matter what" level of safety is impossible in all circumstances, and particularly so when it comes to bicycle helmets. The helmet makes it a little more likely you will survive, maybe even without life-changing injuries, in a larger set of circumstances than riding without a helmet. A helmet is important, much more important is to ride in a way so that you never need the helmet that you are wearing.

much more important is to ride in a way so that you never need the helmet that you are wearing  That only goes so far.  You have zero control over the people, pets, children, wild animals, lions, tigers, and bears around you.

@AndrewHenle If you go biking in a city with people, pets and (more likely problem) other vehicles, then you ride with an appropriate speed and foresight so that anything likely to happen will not end with your head on the asphalt. For the remaining possibilities the helmet will make a difference, but not a large difference compared to the first point. If you go ride in a zoo with big dangerous animals, then I think a shotgun would help more than a helmet.

@AndrewHenle, I disagree. If you take the League of American Bicyclists TS101 ("Traffic Safety 101") class, most of what they teach is riding in a way that communicates your intent to other road users, not just through explicit signaling but also things like lane positioning choices and body language; the classroom part of the course cites statistics that support this making a massive difference in collision frequency and thus injury rate. It's absolutely in your power as a cyclist to make your actions easier to predict (even unconsciously) and thus to reduce the frequency of collisions.

@Nobody If you go biking in a city with people, pets and (more likely problem) other vehicles, then you ride with an appropriate speed and foresight so that anything likely to happen will not end with your head on the asphalt. And that in no way prevents someone from doing something stupid.  There's a reason "to be doored" is a verb.  What happens when a vehicle comes the wrong way on a one-way street around a blind curve? And what happens when something like a deer decides to bolt out from behind a tree and take you out?

@Nobody (cont)  STUFF HAPPENS  no matter how you ride.

The general helmet certification process relates to the absorption of shocks at different angles and speeds, on standard forms of heads, that are supposed to illustrate real-world impacts. Discussing the relevancy of these tests would require to have access to the standard, that is behind a paywall (and if it was, the sales conditions will prevent you from publishing it on the public), so cannot be done here. The tests are also designed to be representative for impact against static obstacles, not for impact against moving vehicles. The standard specifies also a minimum head coverage, and the helmet won't obviously protect the body areas that it doesn't cover.
So a standard sets a minimum level of resistance to some categories of head impacts, which can be sufficient to prevent a serious head injury. It's a "pass or fail" test, and manufacturers can do more if they want. In major markets, there is a mandatory compliance to a standard, so all bicycle helmets are required to comply to these minimum requirements, regardless of their price. To communicate about additional requirements, that can justify a price premium, some manufactureres will use recognized certifications (like MIPS for rotational impact), other will use their own criteria and will brand it (like Trek's WaveCel, also on rotational impact) or add their criteria without specific brand.
NTA-8776 is only mandatory in the Netherlands for speed e-bikes (equivalent of class 3 in US), where it comes from. It completes the EN1708 standard (minimum requirement for "normal" (e-)bike helmets), with higher impact speed and coverage requirements, as the Dutch government considered that the base EN1703 was not sufficient to prevent some head injuries that could results from impacts that can happen at speeds that a speed e-bike can routinely reach. It also sets requirements for visors, if the helmet is equipped with one. That being said, you will have higher protection from motorcycle or full-face helmets, so NTA-8776 not a guarantee of maximal safety for all impacts, but such helmets will probably too heavy and lack ventilation, that is welcome in case of physical activity.

Peachy - you are on the right track.

does the standard reflect a "bare minimum" level of safety, a "you'll be fine no matter what" level of safety, or somewhere in between? If it's in-between, where on the spectrum is it?

Safety should be seen as a spectrum - a range - rather than binary - on or off.

Studies over the last 15 years in the United States, Europe, Australia and New Zealand indicate that bicycle helmets are very effective in decreasing the risk of head and brain injuries

Pros and cons of bicycle helmet legislation from road-safety.transport.ec.europa.eu
This article uses the phrase "very effective in decreasing the risk of head and brain injuries" because there is no such thing as total safety. Helmets only decrease risk of injury in a crash, they don't eliminate it.
To make things more complicated (as if it weren't already) there is no standard scale to use to measure the spectrum.
Helmet standards are an attempt to bring help us have some quantifiable knowledge about the crash worthiness of helmets. That being said - nothing is perfect.
Is a helmet that has not been tested less safe than on that has? We can't know.
What we can know is that a helmet that didn't pass the test is less safe in the test conditions than a helmet that did pass the test.

If a helmet designed for urban, class 3 e-bike riding passes the NTA-8776 standard, will it actually be sufficiently for urban, class 3 e-bike riding? I can imagine several scenarios where meeting the standard doesn't reflect real world safety.

Good question! You have done the research to understand how the helmet was tested and you can imagine some scenarios that were not tested. That will always be the case. There is no such thing as testing for every possible real world scenario.
You aren't purchasing perfect protection when you buy a helmet. You are looking for something that will improve your chances of survival in a crash. Several decision points go into buying a helmet:

How much you want to spend?
Do you like how the helmet looks?
Is the helmet comfortable?
Do you believe the helmet offers sufficient ("sufficient" has it's own set of criteria) protection?
Your decision will be a compromise and a best guess.

Helmets do reduce your chance of head and/or brain injury in a crash and it is good to wear one.
Keep in mind that helmets help you when you crash.
Your first line of defense is to do all the things you should be doing to NOT crash - along with wearing a helmet. Things like following traffic rules, defensive driving etc.

Adding to the decision points:  how is it in the rain - does it run a cold river of water down your neck?

@DDuck IME for any ride longer than 20-30 minutes in any decent rain you'll be soaked to the bone anyway.  The only way you won't wind with rain totally soaking you is if you wear waterproof, completely non-breathable gear, in which case you'll be soaked to the bone with sweat and likely to pass out from overheating.
